# React Formik Autocomplete for Value Selection from Object Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, formik

How to Implement Autocomplete in React with formik for Selecting Both Single and Multiple Values from an Array of Objects?[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekkAi.png)

```
arrayOfObject = [
  { id: 1, name: "test" },
  { id: 2, name: "test1" },
  { id: 3, name: "test2" },
]
< Autocomplete
  id = "userId"
  multiple
  options = { arrayOfObject }
  getOptionLabel = {(option) => option.name}
  onChange = {(event, newValue) => {
    const arrayOfIds = newValue.map((item) => item.id);
    formik.setFieldValue('userId', arrayOfIds);
  }}
  value = {
    ingredients.filter((option) =>
      formik.values.userId.includes(option.id)
    )
  }

    renderInput = {(params) => (
      <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Ingredients"
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        'aria-label': 'Without label',
      }}
      />
  )}
  renderTags = {(value, getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        key={index}
        label={option.name}
        {...getTagProps({ index })}
     />
    ))
  }
  noOptionsText = "Data not found!"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  arrayOfObject = [
  { id: 1, name: "test" },
  { id: 2, name: "test1" },
  { id: 3, name: "test2" },
]
< Autocomplete
  id = "userId"
  multiple
  options = { arrayOfObject }
  getOptionLabel = {(option) => option.name}
  onChange = {(event, newValue) => {
    const arrayOfIds = newValue.map((item) => item.id);
    formik.setFieldValue('userId', arrayOfIds);
  }}
  value = {
    ingredients.filter((option) =>
      formik.values.userId.includes(option.id)
    )
  }

    renderInput = {(params) => (
      <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Ingredients"
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        'aria-label': 'Without label',
      }}
      />
  )}
  renderTags = {(value, getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        key={index}
        label={option.name}
        {...getTagProps({ index })}
     />
    ))
  }
  noOptionsText = "Data not found!"
/>
```

Comment: Isa this an answer? The code looks very similar to that in your question: If it *is* an answer, then you should explain what you have changed and how doing that fixed the problem(s) you were having.